# text area instead of div for bootstrap wysiwyg toolbar

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-wysiwyg

**UPDATE**

Maybe an easier way to put this would be "How can I submit the content that is typed into the `<div>` along with a `<form>` to send it to a database?

**END UPDATE**

I am using bootstrap wysiwyg and have found that it only works when your typing area is a `<div>` like this:

```
<div id="editor" contenteditable="true">
   Start Typing...
</div>
```

and it won't work with a text area like so:

```
<textarea cols="" rows="5" id="editor" contenteditable="true">
  Start Typing...
</textarea>
```

The full javascript code is below although I'm really not sure where the problem lies as the toolbar uses a `data-target='#editor'`

[Click here](https://github.com/mindmup/bootstrap-wysiwyg/blob/master/bootstrap-wysiwyg.js) to go to the github for full code, I just copied and pasted this into a separate js file.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your update: you will have to copy your DIV content into a form's hidden field in client code prior to form submission. Only content of Input/Textarea  elements is sent in GET/POST.

Comment: That's what I thought, I was really confused but I guess I can try to do what you suggested.